# From nand to numbers

Tags: computer-architecture

My understanding is that computers are basically made of nand gates, and that all other gates, such as and, or, etc, can be made from nand gates.

So far so good, but how do we get from nand gates to the things we actually interact with when we program computers, such as numbers, strings, and even collections of things?

For example, how is the binary number 1011 represented in nand gates?

Comment: You might want to read on what a [memory cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_cell_(computing)) is.

Comment: A [flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) is a good start. In essence flip-flop is a device which stores 1 bit in memory. Also note that flip-flop is not necessarily constructed from a pair of NAND gates - it can be a pair NOR gates too. Or even AND-OR trigger or something else